# Use angular and bootstrap to switch image behind a form

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to put a background image on a form and change the image by clicking other images in a list. I was able to put a background image in using CSS, but then I can't figure out how to implement my angular. So I put it in an image tag like I had it previously before implementing my form.

My code snippets are below and any pointers would be appreciated!

```js
app.controller('letterCreateCtrl', function($scope, $state){

$scope.current = 'scLetterHead';

});
```

```css
#responsiveForm{
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  min-height: 650px;
  padding: 80px;
  padding-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="letterForm">
<section id="contact class" class="container content-section text-center">
<div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/scLetterHead.jpg" ng-click="current='scLetterHead'" />
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/scLetterHead2.jpg"  ng-click="current='scLetterHead2'" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/scLetterHead3.jpg" ng-click="current='scLetterHead3'"/>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/scLetterHead4.jpg" ng-click="current='scLetterHead4'"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
          <form id="responsiveForm" action="">
            <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="img/{{current}}.jpg" />
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="occasion">Occasion:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="occasion" name="occasion"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="go"/>
            </div>

            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to wrap a  around my form and give it a class with a z index attribute of 10. After that I was able to position the form on top of the image.